# Limit asymptote of the counts of Erdos numbers

Tags: graph-theory, network

In the graph where nodes are persons and edges follow authorship (that is, having co-authored a peer-reviewed scientific paper), the  [Erdős number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_number) is the number of steps you need to reach mathematician Paul Erdős.

Whenever you progress in a scientific career, your Erdős number necessarily decreases from an infinite value (whenever you published your first paper alone for instance) to a more respectable one. However, Paul Erdős passed away in [1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erd%C5%91s) and since its last publication, nobody on earth would get a number of 1. As time passes, the same will be true for number 2 and so on... Looking overall at the whole demographics, the  counts of Erdős numbers is therefore stabilizing for the lowest numbers.

So my question is, is there any way of predicting the shape of this count as time would reach eternity?

Comment: I once met [a woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Alice,_Countess_of_Athlone) who met the woman in whose honour [the ball before the battle of Waterloo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duchess_of_Richmond%27s_ball) was held in 1815 (one of the daughters of the Duke and Duchess of Richmond).  So two centuries in two steps is not difficult